# How to crop a large jpeg into smaller tile jpegs?

Tags: image-processing

For example, I have a big.jpg which is 600 (w) x 300 (h), I would like to crop it into 250 x 250 each. Such that `big.jpg` becomes 6 tile jpegs:

```
tile_0_0.jpg (250 x 250)
tile_0_1.jpg (250 x 250)
tile_0_2.jpg (100 x 250)
tile_1_0.jpg (250 x 50)
tile_1_1.jpg (250 x 50)
tile_1_2.jpg (100 x 50)
```

Any tool (command line or GUI) to recommended? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Answer (score 0):

My favorite tool to do that kind of thing is [GD](http://www.boutell.com/gd/).

Answer (score 0):

for windows, I typically use windows image resizer powertoys clone:
http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/

After you install it, just right click a group of images in explorer, click resize, choose your size and bam. It does the rest :)